# How to I prevent lamda function local variables from changing in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, lambda, anonymous-function, anonymous

Suppose someone wants to make a lambda function, and they want everything in the lambda function, except for the input arguments, to be treated like a function's local variables. How would they accomplish that? By saying that the variables are "local," I mean that there is no access to those variables from outside of the lambda function.

## Code

```
right = 5

demo_lamb = lambda left : print("INSIDE  LAMB left == ", left, ",", "right == ", right)

for lt in range(0, 5):
    demo_lamb(lt)
    right = 100*lt + 99
    print("OUTSIDE LAMB              right == ", right)
```

## Printed Output

```
INSIDE  LAMB left ==  0 , right ==  5
OUTSIDE LAMB              right ==  99
INSIDE  LAMB left ==  1 , right ==  99
OUTSIDE LAMB              right ==  199
INSIDE  LAMB left ==  2 , right ==  199
OUTSIDE LAMB              right ==  299
INSIDE  LAMB left ==  3 , right ==  299
OUTSIDE LAMB              right ==  399
INSIDE  LAMB left ==  4 , right ==  399
OUTSIDE LAMB              right ==  499
```

## Desired Output

```
INSIDE  LAMB left ==  0 , right ==  5
OUTSIDE LAMB              right ==  99
INSIDE  LAMB left ==  1 , right ==  5
OUTSIDE LAMB              right ==  199
INSIDE  LAMB left ==  2 , right ==  5
OUTSIDE LAMB              right ==  299
INSIDE  LAMB left ==  3 , right ==  5
OUTSIDE LAMB              right ==  399
INSIDE  LAMB left ==  4 , right ==  5
OUTSIDE LAMB              right ==  499
```

How do we "freeze" the value of all of the variables inside of a lambda function (except the input arguments) to be what they were when the lambda function was created?

## One Failed Solution

Importing `copy` and replacing `right` inside the lambda function with `copy.deepcopy(right)` makes no difference to the output whatsoever.

Comment: you have to bind the variable to the lambda function.

Comment: If you are using `some_var = lambda <whatever>` you shouldn't be using a `lambda` in the first place, it defeats the **only advantage** which is that a `lambda` is anonymous.

Comment: And the problem is that `right` isn't a local variable, it is a *free variable* closed over the function. The problem is that Python has lexical scoping, so `right` always refers to the `right` in the global scope. The best thing to do is just to make it a parameter. Also, this has nothing to do with `lambda` functions, but **all functions work this way**

Answer (score 2):

The usual trick, which dates to before the introduction of closures at all, is to use "optional parameters":

```
demo_lamb = lambda left, right=right: print("INSIDE  LAMB left == ", left, ",", "right == ", right)
```

Default arguments are evaluated when the function is defined, which is exactly what you want.